# Why is CRC16 calculation so slow?

Tags: c#, crc, crc16

I have the following CRC function:

```
public static ushort ComputeCRC16(byte[] data)
{
    ushort i, j, crc = 0;
    int size = data.Length;

    for (i = 0; i < size - 2; i++)
    {
        crc ^= (ushort)(data[i] << 8);

        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            if ((crc & 0x8000) != 0) /* Test for bit 15 */
            {
                crc = (ushort)((crc << 1) ^ 0x1234); /* POLYNOMIAL */
            }
            else
            {
                crc <<= 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return crc;
}
```

I have been trying to use it to calculate a CRC16 from a file that is around 800 Kb, but it takes forever, I mean after five minutes, the value of `i` was still at around 2 000, and it should go up to 800 000.

Can someone give me an explanation on why it is so slow and what I can do to solve this issue ?

I'm working with Visual Studio 2015 on a i7 processor and the computer is not old nor broken.

Comment: Whats is `Ko` ?

Comment: I thing the compiler overcomplicates the optimization, the code looks solid enough; try adding `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]` to the function, it might help

Comment: I don't see there any problem, that should cause such a slow speed. In standard implementation a pre-build table is used and whole bytes are processed at once *(not per bit, as it is here)*. The current implementation should be slow, but IMHO not this slow.

Comment: @TheGeneral Kb, sorry french speaker here (o is for octet, which means byte)

Comment: @zedling im not sure that will do much at all

Comment: @zedling I just tried but no visible effect

Comment: What is `byte[] data` - array of all data in file on next 16 bits for CRC16? It looks like 16 bits but you write about value 2000 of `i`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace the first lines with:

```
int i, j;
ushort crc = 0;
```

You were using a `ushort` for the `for` counter, but if `size` > 65535, the `for` cycle won't ever end.

The reason for this is that C# by default does not throw an Exception if an overflow occurs but just "silently" ignores it. Checkout the following code for a demonstration:

```
ushort i = ushort.MaxValue; //65535  
i++; //0
```

Comment: damn, we missed that

Comment: Glory to unchecked by default

Comment: I actually feel stupid right now, but didn't know unchecked was the default... I did it again with checked and got an overflow... Thanks anyway

Comment: @MartinVerjans Are you coming from VB.NET? because I think there it is default...

Comment: @Freggar Yes actually, a few monthes since I'm back to C#